# LTC3862 GATE Pin always high and switch on?

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply

Switch Mode Power Supply[image: ][1][1]]**LTC3862-1 GATE PIN(1-2) ALWAYS HIGH and MOSFET Gate Pın ON**

We are using a LTC3862 for a SMPS (switching mode power supply, 24V to 130V, 0.5A).
Firstly, we modelled the design in LTSpice and it worked better than the design installed on the perforated plate.

The MOSFET's gate pin is always on ("high") and the LTC3862 gate pin voltage value is 5V constantly. In LTSpice, the LTC3862 gate pin value is 0V to 10V and it is working. What could be causing this?

[image: SMPS (LTC3862)]

[image: Simulation]

[image: SMPS's Circuit]
Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: It looks like that part is only available in small SMD packages. That, and the fact that proper layout is important for switching converters, makes "perforated plate" sound like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: some kind of engineering data should be available to comment, like a ruff schematic with component values, How your perforated pcb looks like

Comment: Could you please show us the schematic and, if possible, some photos of the setup with your "delikli pertinaks"?

Comment: Judging from the picture: it might've worked... Briefly. I don't see any decoupling cap *on* the little PCB, right next to the chip, and those long wires going to the MOSFET gates...(with no damping resistors either). It's going to ring like a bell and possibly exceed some maximum voltages. Design a proper PCB first...